# Direct converting a const char* text passed through a function into a vector of chars

Tags: c++, arrays, char, type-conversion

Imagine that `MyTextClass` is a custom class that in this case would hold the passed const char `"Hello stackoverflowers"` into a `std::vector<char>`:

```
class MyTextClass{
    private:
        std::vector<char> storage;
    public:
        MyTextClass(const char* _passedchars) //constructor
}
```

With something like the code above, I want to initialize an instance of `MyTextClass` by passing a text to it:

```
MyTextClass textholder("Hello stackoverflowers");
```

Or even the following if I overload the `=` operator within `MyTextClass`:

```
MyTextClass textholder = "Hello stackoverflowers";
```

The problem becomes figuring out what the definition of the `MyTextClass` constructor should look like. I say that because while there is no problem in the constructor receiving a `const char` passed directly as text like `"Hello stackoverflowers"`, that is an array an thus its length:

1) can't be devised in advance (because it's a passed text of unknown length);

2) nor figured out within the constructor (because `sizeof(_passedchars)/sizeof(_passedchars[0])` will only assess the the size of the pointer;

3) and also not retrieved with `std::size` or the use of `std::begin` and `std::end`, since there is no implementation of those for `const char`.

And without such informations, I just can't figure it out how to convert the `const char` parameter `_passedchars` of the constructor of `MyTextClass` into the internal `std::vector<char>` that I called `storage` in the code example above.

Therefore, how could I convert the passed `const char` into a `std:vector<char>` within a function, in the case of wanting to create an own char text class?

Comment: You should take a `const char*` and the size can be determined with `strlen` (assuming it's a null-terminated c-string)

Comment: @WhozCraig Correct, that's what I meant in the example-code. Edited to correct

Comment: @BriannaSzvenska ok that said, content length has to be conveyed *somehow*. If it is nulchar terminated string, that length can be deduced via `strlen`. If it isn't then you need to provide an additional length param.

Comment: Unless this is some form of exercise, why would you use a vector of char instead of a std::string?

Comment: @kfsone if by form of exercise you mean just an attempt to learn an unknown detail of the language, that's exactly what I'm trying to.

Comment: @tkausl That did the trick. Indeed I can make it so as to guarantee that all passed text is of a null-terminated c-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use this exact constructor declaration you could write (in the class definition in the header):

```
MyTextClass(const char* _passedchars)
    : storage( _passedchars, _passedchars + strlen(_passedchars) )
{
}
```

(note: requires `#include <string.h>` for `strlen`).

However the string literal is actually an array.  By accepting a pointer you lost the length information which was already available. So you could instead have the constructor as:

```
template<size_t N>
MyTextClass( const char (&passed)[N] )
    : storage( passed, passed + N - 1 )
{
}
```

In the latter case you could use `std::begin(passed), std::end(passed)` instead.

Comment: I see what you are suggesting and I certainly like it better, but it's giving me the error `Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall chars::chars<23>(char const (&)[23])" (??$?0$0M@@chars@@QAE@AAY0M@$$CBD@Z)`, in the Visual Studio 2015 debugger.

Comment: @BriannaSzvenska you made a mistake somewhere, impossible to say more without seeing your code.  In case it was not clear, the code in my answer goes in the class definition

Comment: I just copied and pasted your suggestion over my constructor in cpp and updated the header file accordingly.

Comment: The two constructor definitions here produced different object states.

Comment: @BriannaSzvenska my code is for the header file, unmodified. If you put it in cpp file you would get an error

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Good spotting

Comment: Oh, I see. I didn't realize that you were proposing to move the function definition directly to the header file, which does make sense due to the use of templates. Now that I have erased the constructor from the cpp file and just let it at header, it works perfectly. Thanks, this solutions the most elegant and one and does not rely on any external library, not even on `std`. I have no reputation yet to upvote your answer, but I will certainly accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`strlen`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen) to determine the length of a C-style string.

Alternatively, you could change the parameter type to `std::string` and use its `size` or `length` function to get the length of the string.